# java generics vs dynamically loading class using Class.forName()

Tags: java, generics, dynamic-class-creation

Assume I am making a class called Government. Government has members like officers, ministers, departments etc. For each of those members I create an interface, and any specific government defines them as they like.

The main method in the Government class is called `Serve(Request req)`. Assume that the query rate is very large (1000+ queries per second).

To create the government, I can:
1) Use Java generics to write `Government<Class Minister, Class Officer, ...>` and any specific government implementation needs to create its own Government object in java code, and a `main()` to have deployable jar.

2) Have a configuration file which specifies the class names of officers, ministers etc., and whenever `Serve()` is called, it uses `Class.forName()`and `Class.newInstance()` to create an  object of the class. Any new government just needs to write classes for its members, and the configuration file. There is one single `main()` for all governments.

From a purely performance point of view - which is better and why? My main concerns are:

a) does `forName()` execute a costly search every time? Assume a very large universe of classes.

b) Do we miss out on the compiler optimizations that might be performed in case 1 but not in case 2 on the dynamic classes?

Comment: why don't you measure the performance of both methods?

Comment: I could do that...am hoping someone already "knows" :-)

Comment: As generics shouldn't matter your question boils down to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647111/newinstance-vs-new

Comment: I agree newInstance() vs new should not matter much. But does forName() matter? Do we need a costly search every time?

Comment: `forName()` should be called just once per class to load it, and not each time you're creating a new instance...

Comment: But if its called everytime it might slow things down noticeably?

Comment: My guess is yes, because it does security checks and some natively implemented logic...

Comment: Generics don't make sense here.

Comment: Okay....I guess it is foolish to call forName() here for every request - so some of the above discussion is academic. It might just be useful to see the scope of compiler optimization.

Comment: `Government<Class Minister, Class Officer, ...>` is not remotely valid syntax and I have no idea what you mean here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you reuse your goverment object,  there is no difference at runtime.  Difference isonly at object creation time.

1 & 2 differ in concept - 1 ist hardwired, while 2 is dynamic ( you may even use DI contrainers like spring,  guice or pico  - basically you proposed to write your own )

As for forName() performance -   it is up on classloader ( and also on container ) . MOst of them would cache name resolution results, look up in  map -  but I can not speak for all

As for optimisations - there are compiler optimisations, and also agressive runtime optiomisations from JIT compilers - they matter more.

Comment: Both design paradigms are useful dependent on the situation. My question was just about performance.

Comment: You are not answering from *purely performance point of view*

Comment: from purely eprfromance point of view it does not matter.  In any case claases will have to be loaded  and instantiated.  Configurable solution will have some overhead on startupm, but it can be neglected

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda I have modified the original question to be more specific. Can you take a look again?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it. Those two are not alternatives; they are pretty much orthogonal: Generics is a compile-time construct. It is erased and does not translate to anything at runtime. On the other hand, loading classes by calling `forName` is a runtime thing. One does not affect the other.

If you are using generics, then that means you don't need the class object at runtime, since in generics you don't have access to the class object, unless you pass it in explicitly. If you don't need the class object at runtime, that means you don't need to load it with `forName`, so that is inconsistent with `forName`. If you do pass the class object in explicitly, then that means you already have the class object and don't need to load it, also inconsistent with `forName`.

Answer (score 0):

Your description kind of reads like this to me: "I want to use dependency injection, should I roll my own?"

Look into Spring (or Guice by Google).  I'll assume Spring.

Create interfaces for stuff and configure which implementation to use for each in Spring.